# CSS Positioning Issue. Unable to add second sidebar

Tags: html, css

I am unable to add 2 sidebars in a sample webpage that I made today.

HTML :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<!-- saved from url=(0045)http://csseasy.com/layouts/fixed/1column.html -->

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <meta name="generator" content=
  "HTML Tidy for Linux/x86 (vers 25 March 2009), see www.w3.org" />
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=us-ascii" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style2.css" />

  <title>CSSeasy.com example page</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="header"></div>

  <div id="content"></div>

  <div id="ltsidebar"></div>

  <div id="rtsidebar">
    <div id="footer"></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
body
{
    width:1400px;
}

#header
{
    background-color:#666;
    height:150px;
    margin-left:250px;
    width:750px;
}

#content
{
    background-color:#666;
    height:auto!important;
    margin-bottom:20px;
    margin-left:250px;
    margin-top:20px;
    min-height:500px;
    width:750px;
}

#footer
{
    background-color:#666;
    height:100px;
    margin-left:250px;
    margin-top:0;
    width:750px;
}

#ltsidebar
{
    background-color:#666;
    float:left;
    height:300px;
    margin-bottom:20px;
    margin-top:-500px;
    width:200px;
}

#rtsidebar
{
    background-color:#666;
    float:right;
    height:300px;
    margin-bottom:20px;
    margin-right:160px;
    margin-top:-500px;
    width:200px;
}
```

I was able to add one sidebar floating to the left. But when I made another div for right sidebar, and increased 'body' width from 960px to 1400 px then I see that the footbar is on the right. Why? I want the footbar to be seated at the bottom only. So my question is why did the footer move to the right? And what is the solution for it?

Comment: Can you make a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)? Don't define the width of `body` in px.

Comment: Moving your footer outside your right sidebar seems to fix it, but im not sure i understood your problem. Anyway, here is a fiddle with your code (footer moved out of sidebar): http://jsfiddle.net/E3SMb/ Use it in your question to help people understand the problem

Comment: Yes, that was I was asking for. Thanks for the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if You use float elements you have to clear this floating.

**HTML CODE**

```
  <div id="header"></div>
  <div class="wrapper">
      <div id="ltsidebar"></div>
      <div id="content"></div>      
      <div id="rtsidebar">
  </div>   
  <div id="footer"></div>
```

**CSS CODE**

```
body
{
    width:1400px;
}

#header
{
    background-color:#666;
    height:150px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width:750px;
}

#content
{
    background-color:#666;
    height:auto!important;
    margin: 20px 125px;
    min-height:500px;
    width:750px;
    float: left;
}

#footer
{
    background-color:#666;
    height:100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width:750px;
    clear: both;
}

#ltsidebar
{
    float:left;
    width:200px;
    height:300px;
    background-color:#666;
}

#rtsidebar
{
    float:right;
    width:200px;
    height:300px;
    margin-bottom:20px;
    background-color:#666;  
}
```

**DEMO**

http://jsfiddle.net/SmXKj/2/

Comment: Thanks :) Though I never understood properly, how clear property works. Any nice tutorial?

Comment: can you help me for this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23435681/unable-to-specify-css-position-fixed

Answer (score 2):

Try out this to keep the footer at bottom:

```
  <div id="header"></div>

  <div id="content"></div>

  <div id="ltsidebar"></div>

  <div id="rtsidebar">

  </div>
  <div id="footer"></div>
```

I have moved footer div section out of the rtsidebar and placed it below rtsidebar.