# unable to specify css position=fixed

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have 3 vertical div i.e right-sidebar, content, left-sidebar.
When user scroll the page i want to fixed the right-sidebar to the top. 
[Like this image](http://my.jetscreenshot.com/demo/20140502-qxks-311kb.jpg)

[image: figure 1]

But currently when ever i scroll my page down , the second sidebar overlapps with first sidebar as shown  in [this image.](http://my.jetscreenshot.com/demo/20140502-uzeh-291kb.jpg)
What is the reason? anyone please help me.
-thanks

[image: figure 2]

---

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        function fixDiv() {
    var $div = $("#navwrap");
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > $div.data("top")) { 
        $('#navwrap').css({'position': 'fixed','z-index': '1', 'top': '0'}); 
    }
    else {
        $('#navwrap').css({'position': 'static', 'top': 'auto'});
    }
} 
$(document).ready(function () {
       $("#navwrap").data("top", $("#navwrap").offset().top); // set original position on load
$(window).scroll(fixDiv);
});
     </script>
```

HTML code

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row clearfix">
        <div class="col-md-3 column" id="navwrap">
            <div class="btn-group">
                 <button class="btn btn-default" type="button"><em class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-left"></em></button> <button class="btn btn-default" type="button"><em class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-center"></em></button> <button class="btn btn-default" type="button"><em class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-right"></em></button> <button class="btn btn-default" type="button"><em class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-justify"></em> Justify</button>
            </div>
            <div class="row clearfix">
                <div class="col-md-12 column">
                    <div class="btn-group">
                         <button class="btn btn-default">Action</button> <button data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle"><span class="caret"></span></button>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Action</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="disabled">
                                <a href="#">Another action</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="divider">
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Something else here</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="list-group">
                 <a href="#" class="list-group-item active">Home</a>
                <div class="list-group-item">
                    List header
                </div>
                <div class="list-group-item">
                    <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">
                        List group item heading
                    </h4>
                    <p class="list-group-item-text">
                        ...
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="list-group-item">
                    <span class="badge">14</span>Help
                </div> <a class="list-group-item"><span class="badge">14</span>Help</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-9 column">
            <div class="row clearfix">
                <div class="col-md-9 column">
                    <p>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <strong>consectetur adipiscing elit</strong>. Aliquam eget sapien sapien. Curabitur in metus urna. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Phasellus eu sem sapien, sed vestibulum velit. Nam purus nibh, lacinia non faucibus et, pharetra in dolor. Sed iaculis posuere diam ut cursus. <em>Morbi commodo sodales nisi id sodales. Proin consectetur, nisi id commodo imperdiet, metus nunc consequat lectus, id bibendum diam velit et dui.</em> Proin massa magna, vulputate nec bibendum nec, posuere nec lacus. <small>Aliquam mi erat, aliquam vel luctus eu, pharetra quis elit. Nulla euismod ultrices massa, et feugiat ipsum consequat eu.</small>
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 column">
                    <p>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <strong>consectetur adipiscing elit</strong>. Aliquam eget sapien sapien. Curabitur in metus urna. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Phasellus eu sem sapien, sed vestibulum velit. Nam purus nibh, lacinia non faucibus et, osuere nec lacus. <small>Aliquam mi erat, aliquam vel luctus eu, pharetra quis elit. Nulla euismod ultrices massa, et feugiat ipsum consequat eu.</small>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: anyone please help me ,, waiting for your reply

Comment: To start, $div.data("top") should be $div.offset().top

Comment: @ashack Not working. My right-sidebar contents are not getting fixed if i scroll my page down.  I tried  your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the bootstrap so I think it's obvious to use its [affix](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#affix) feature.


[**Link for jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Nicolai8/cj57q/2/)


Just wrap all content of `.col-sm-3` in another `div` and add attributes `data-spy`, `data-offset-top` and `data-offset-bottom` and according to them bootstrap will do all the work.


Otherwise you can use javascript code:

```
$('.sidebar').affix({offset:{
                        top:60,
                        bottom:200
                     });
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <div class="sidebar" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="60" data-offset-bottom="200">
                <div class="btn-group">
                    <button class="btn btn-default" type="button"><em class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-left"></em></button>
                    <button class="btn btn-default" type="button"><em class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-center"></em></button>
                    <button class="btn btn-default" type="button"><em class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-right"></em></button>
                    <button class="btn btn-default" type="button"><em class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-justify"></em>Justify</button>
                </div>
                <div class="row clearfix">
                    <div class="col-md-12 column">
                        <div class="btn-group">
                            <button class="btn btn-default">Action</button>
                            <button data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle"><span class="caret"></span></button>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Action</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="disabled">
                                    <a href="#">Another action</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="divider"></li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Something else here</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="list-group">
                    <a href="#" class="list-group-item active">Home</a>
                    <div class="list-group-item">
                        List header
                    </div>
                    <div class="list-group-item">
                        <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">List group item heading
                        </h4>
                        <p class="list-group-item-text">
                            ...
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="list-group-item">
                        <span class="badge">14</span>Help
                    </div>
                    <a class="list-group-item"><span class="badge">14</span>Help</a>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <div class="col-md-9">
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <strong>consectetur adipiscing elit</strong>. Aliquam eget sapien sapien. Curabitur in metus urna. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Phasellus eu sem sapien, sed vestibulum velit. Nam purus nibh, lacinia non faucibus et, pharetra in dolor. Sed iaculis posuere diam ut cursus. <em>Morbi commodo sodales nisi id sodales. Proin consectetur, nisi id commodo imperdiet, metus nunc consequat lectus, id bibendum diam velit et dui.</em> Proin massa magna, vulputate nec bibendum nec, posuere nec lacus. <small>Aliquam mi erat, aliquam vel luctus eu, pharetra quis elit. Nulla euismod ultrices massa, et feugiat ipsum consequat eu.</small>
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <strong>consectetur adipiscing elit</strong>. Aliquam eget sapien sapien. Curabitur in metus urna. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Phasellus eu sem sapien, sed vestibulum velit. Nam purus nibh, lacinia non faucibus et, osuere nec lacus. <small>Aliquam mi erat, aliquam vel luctus eu, pharetra quis elit. Nulla euismod ultrices massa, et feugiat ipsum consequat eu.</small>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you are position the sidebar fixed, you take it out of the document flow.

That is, the content div is sitting next to the sidebar, when the sidebar is removed, the content naturally flows as far left as it can go.

If you were to position the sidebar on the right hand side of the screen, the content would stay in the same position.

One solution would be to dynamically (with jQuery) add a left margin to the content div when the sidebar goes fixed.

Comment: what you said is right!  but if i do so then browser issue can come, don't know how much exactly i have to reduce the width in pixel, it may work in my system browser but may be not working with other browser. any  better solution please think, if could not find then at last i will implement what you said above. thanks

Comment: Not sure how you mean how much to reduce the width in pixel?
`[when the sidebar goes sticky] {
  var offLeft = $('.sidebar').outerWidth();
  $('.main-content-div').css({
     position: 'relative',
     left: offLeft
   });
[close sticky listener]`

Answer (score 0):

You could try the [stickyMojo](http://mojotech.github.io/stickymojo/) plugin.

Comment: Could you be more specific, or share a jsfiddle or URL?